# Wix and running application after setup with WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX disabled

Tags: wix

I found how to run an application after install with the [following documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm).

I know with the `WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT` property I can tweak the checkbox text.

I know with the `WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX` property I can set the checkbox to checked by default.

My question is does anyone know is it possible to display the checkbox BUT have it disabled (not editable)?

Basically I want to have the checkbox show and be checked but I don't want the user to be able to uncheck it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to override the `Dialog` and `Control` using the techniques described in the [Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm) to add the `Disabled='true'` attribute. It'll take a bit of work but should be possible.